# Do something if product type is changed

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I have a custom WooCommerce product type.
If you switched between the standard WooCommerce type the input are cleared but this does not work for custom types.

So I created a jQuery for this

```
$('#product-type').on('change', function() {
  //do something
});
```

But this is not the solution because the functions in this code are also running if the page is refreshed.

What can I do to let this work only if the product type is changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce set the product type with JavaScript and is not set wit PHP.
They use the change function if the page is loading and set the right product type on screen.

If you need a function on a specific product type you can do something like this

```
$('#product-type').on('change', function() {
    if($('#product-type').val() == '//your type'){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside the ready event. The code inside this function fires only when the DOM is completely loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#product-type').on('change', function() {
        //do something
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Fernando thanks for te reaction. I tried this but it fixed not the issue. It is very strange that the on change function is running if the page is loaded.

Comment: Hello Jan, you're welcome. Let's try to put a breakpoint in event listener through Chrome. Press F12 to open Console > Go to tab "Source" >  on the right pane look for "Event Listener Breakpoint" and then expand the list "control" and mark "change" event so you can debug your js code. This will break in every change event fired.

Comment: Hi Fernando I followed your advise and chrome says "no breakpoints"